# Chrome doesn't render div or span revisited

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been googling and grepping for a while. Haven't found a solution yet. I'm attaching some sample html. This is generated by a third party package that is used in DNN. Chrome fails to display the element as noted. IE9 and FF are fine. Any comments appreciated.

```
<div>
    <table align="left" sizcache="18" sizset="196" style="height: 100%;">
          <tbody sizcache="18" sizset="196">
              <tr>
                <td>
                   <span>
                   I can see this element... 
                   </span>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <span style="width: 450px; height: 100px; display: inline-block;">
                        You can see me in IE9, Firefox, but not Chrome!!! 
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 10px;" colspan="2">
                ... and this element.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I took your code threw it into an HTML page generated by TextPad and it works fine in Chrome. The DocType is '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">' Maybe your doc type is putting your browser in quirks mode or something similar and keeping it from displaying properly. I can put up the whole sample page if you think it will help.

Comment: FYI Changed the DocType to 4.0 and it failed to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the two overflows in your div style. http://jsfiddle.net/zeuFT/1/

Comment: Hi Guys - I had the sample code loaded up in MS Expression Web 4. It did squawk at the overflows (as well as a couple of other attributes - sizcache, sizset, align, etc.). Removing the overflows did solve the problem. Thanks! What a great forum.

Comment: Hi Guys - A little follow up for those interested... using IE9 and Chrome Developer tools, I modified the attributes using the recommendations listed in this topic. Changing colspan="2" to ="1" in Chrome DevTools did not display the span content. Removing the overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; did display the content as noted above. 

The schema for the document being used is:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

The attributes "overflow-x and overflow-y" are not supported by this current schema.

Answer (score 0):

The div is set to `height: 100%;`, but the parent has no height defined, so it's 100% of nothing.

Adding a height to the parent `td` will show the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/2msKf/2/

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is incorect HTML.
Please observe that there is only 1 TD in each row, but the TD with div that is not being displayed has colspan="2" .. i believe that chrome cannot handle this